# Image not resizing CSS/HTML

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to resize a logo image in my header for a website. The header consists on two elements: logo, and navbar. Logo to the left, and navbar to the right. So far my code is:

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div id = "logo">
        <img src = "./media/logo/logo.jpg">
    </div>

    <nav>
        <ul id = "navbar">
            <li><a href = "#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1080px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

header #logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

header #logo img {
    width: 200px;
}

header nav {
    width: 850px;
    float: right:
    margin-top: 30px;
}

header nav ul {
    float: right;
}

header nav ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

The image file has a width of 268px, meaning it should downscale to 200px, as written in the CSS code. However, the image instead upscales to around 300px. I've tried also changing the HTML img tag to:

```
<img src = "./media/logo/logo.jpg" style = "width: 200px">
```

and

```
<img src = "./media/logo/logo.jpg" width = "200">
```

yet it still upscales to ~300px rather than downscaling to 200px. Curiously enough, it is able to upscale properly. Downscaling is the problem.

Comment: This code is okay, problem has to be elsewhere. No inline style or width attribute needed in this case, I've used HTML/CSS from your question. See the result https://jsfiddle.net/6g4heou8/, image has 200px width.

Comment: Than follow my fiddle. Used the same code, it's working as expected. Maybe you have just zoomed your site or whatever, code is okay.

Comment: Your CSS as presented scales down to 200px : https://jsfiddle.net/q01kaaj1/ . At least in Chrome.

Comment: Do you have another css styles beside you show above?

Comment: found the bug! instead of writing at the start of the css file *body { min-width: 400px;}, i wrote *{min-width: 400px}. Yep, no dark magic happening here!

Answer (score 1):

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1080px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

header #logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

header #logo img {
    width: 150px;
}

header nav {
    width: 850px;
    float: right:
    margin-top: 30px;
}

header nav ul {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div id = "logo">
        <img src = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a">
    </div>

    <nav>
        <ul id = "navbar">
            <li><a href = "#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Yea your code is not problem. I think you have referred another CSS. This is your runnable code, I have changed the width of the image here. check it out.!!

Comment: Yeah, I figured out the bug was at the start of the CSS file where instead of writing *body{min-width: 400px}, I wrote *{min-width:400px}. Quite a peculiar mistake. Didn't added in the code provided for the question as it seems like something nobody should get wrong :p

Comment: nice to heard from you